# How to manage multiple supervisord's from one web interface?

Tags: supervisord

I have 4 servers in my production setup, on these server I have supervisord to monitor and manage processes.

Is there a way to manage multiple supervisord's from one supervisorctl web interface ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Nope, because the UI is run from within each supervisor. However, you could build something or there might be something out there that leverages the XML-RPC API that is run behind the same servers to aggregate them.

Someone on the mailinglist pointed this out: https://github.com/aleszoulek/django-dashvisor ... unfortunately it looks abandoned.